# How do I use a named_scope to limit records to those which are not blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have built a Ruby on Rails application (2.3.9) which allows users to track workouts. I am trying to only return records from my `Workout` table which have a value in the `video_link` column. (`workout.video_link` is a string and contains a web address).

I have used a `named_scope` to limit records before but only on columns which were integers, I am not sure how to do this with a string as the `IS NOT NULL` obviously won't work here.

How would I write the scope in `workout.rb` to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify conditions as a string to check `IS NOT NULL`:

```
class Workout
  named_scope :with_link, :conditions => "video_link IS NOT NULL AND video_link != ''"
end
```

Comment: This doesn't limit the records thought because `workout.video_link` doesn't contain `NULL`. It is blank.

Comment: *updated so that you are checking for not NULL and for != ''.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Pan Thomakos' example:

```
class Workout
  named_scope :with_link, :conditions => 'LENGTH(TRIM(video_link)) > 0'
end
```

Comment: I would add the AND video_link IS NOT NULL condition to the clause.  It's still possible for the field to be null, or for it to be an empty string.  But this is probably the way to go.

Comment: Even if the field is NULL, the above will still work. However, One reason to add `IS NOT NULL` could be to improve performance - adding it might have a significant performance improvement if many records will have that field as `NULL`.